# How do I fetch the price from this page? I was able to get the title, but I do not know how to format soup.find() to get the price

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = 'https://www.target.com/p/lego-technic-mclaren-formula-1-race-car-42141-model-building-kit/-/A-83783490#lnk=sametab'


page = requests.get(URL, headers=headers)


soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')


title = soup.find(class_="sc-ipEyDJ gnavnm h-text-bold h-margin-b-tight").get_text()
price = soup.find('span', {'class': 'styles__CurrentPriceFontSize-sc-1mdemp3-1 dUPDAJ'})
```

I tried formatting the soup.find() method multiple ways, but I keep getting an empty list. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you looked at the HTML source code for that page, using View Source in your browser?  There is no tag like that in the source, and that's what `requests` reads.  The page is built dynamically with Javascript.  There is a JSON object with the price in there.  You can search for that, or you can use Selenium to execute the Javascript.

Comment: In logs there is a request which return all of the data, where field `price.current_retail` contains raw price: https://redsky.target.com/redsky_aggregations/v1/web/pdp_client_v1?key=9f36aeafbe60771e321a7cc95a78140772ab3e96&tcin=83783490&is_bot=false&member_id=0&pricing_store_id=3991&has_pricing_store_id=true&has_financing_options=true&visitor_id=0185B2DB0ED502018E3198E713464B69&has_size_context=true&latitude=43.530&longitude=-5.680&zip=33207&state=O&channel=WEB&page=/p/A-83783490

Answer (score 0):

The price and some other information are rendered dynamically with Javascript fetching an API. You need to either find how to mimic the call using requests or use Selenium.

Comment: Okay. I am going to try to use Selenium to mimic the call, and get see if it works.